# C# how to update file(leave old data)

Tags: c#

Now I'm writing to a file:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:/duom.txt");
tw.WriteLine("Text1");
```

When i writen second time all data delete and write new.

How update data? Leave old data and add new

Comment: lol, the whole point of using the @ symbol with the string is so you can use a normal \ folder separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to specify `true` for the `Append` flag (in one of the [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter_members.aspx) constructor overloads):

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:/duom.txt", true);
```

NB: Don't forget to wrap in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileMode.Append

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullUrl, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [constructor overload with the append flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328969.aspx), and don't forget to make sure your stream is closed when you're finished:

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\duom.txt", true))
{
    tw.WriteLine("Text1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the [FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx).  You can use:

```
var tw = File.Open(@"D:\duom.txt", FileMode.Append);
tw.WriteLine("Text1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:/duom.txt", true);
```

Will append to the file instead of overwriting it

Answer (score 0):

You could use File.AppendText like this:

```
TextWriter tw = File.AppendText(@"D:/duom.txt");
tw.WriteLine("Text1");
tw.Close();
```