# Filestream file and Streamwriter in foreach and add line when done

Tags: c#, streamwriter

It's like that that right now I'm trying to open my file with FileStream where I saw a little further into the code to use streamwriter compared to writing it into the file every time it goes through Streamwriter.

When it runs through the first time then do it without any problems but as soon as I run it through the second lap. then it fails where it then writes "**Stream was not writable**"

```cs
int count = 0;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\jpe\Projekt\Utilities\Icons\Icons/WriteLines.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    foreach (SPSite tmpSite in tmpRootColl)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title {0}", tmpSite.RootWeb.Title));
        //Enumerate through each sub-site
        foreach (SPWeb tmpWeb in tmpSite.AllWebs)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title {0}", tmpWeb.Title));
            //Enumerate through each List
            foreach (SPList tmpList in tmpWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (tmpList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title {0}", tmpList.Title));
                    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fs)) //Errors come here when it runs the second round through.
                    {
                        await outputFile.WriteLineAsync($"{tmpSite.RootWeb.Title} - {tmpList.Title} {count}");
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________");
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve with this is that it has to insert text into the file every time it runs through StreamWriter. It should not first make it to the last when it is finished.

i have read:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7306243/18055701

[C# how to update file(leave old data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861920/c-sharp-how-to-update-fileleave-old-data)

Comment: Move the `using StreamWriter` up out of the nested `foreach`es.

Comment: @Fildor before `foreach (SPList tmpList in tmpWeb.Lists)` or `SPSite tmpSite` ??

Comment: Out of the outermost foreach. So it's SPSite, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're creating a `StreamWriter`, writing to it, and disposing it for every list, this is what's causing the issue. Internally the `Dispose` method closes the underlying stream causing the exception. To solve this we can do one of 2 things

1. Tell our `StreamWriter` to not close the underlying stream.
2. Not dispose our `StreamWriter` until we're also done with the underlying stream.

Here's how to do #1:

Simply replace your call to the constructor with this

```cs
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fs, leaveOpen: true))
```

Here's how to do #2:

Move the `using (StreamWriter ...` block up to be "one level deeper" than the `using (FileStream ...` block

```cs
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("..."))
{
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        // Your foreach loops here
    }
}
```

Personally I'd go with #2 as I'm not a fan of creating and disposing objects in a loop

Comment: Thanks for help me! :) Good day to u

Comment: Here to help, have a nice day yourself

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using at least .NET framework 4.5.

The `StreamWriter` closes the base stream in its `Dispose()` method. You can adjust that behavior by using another construcor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-io-stream-system-text-encoding-system-int32-system-boolean)

Comment: Or you can just leave it open until you are actually done writing.

Comment: I have 4.7.2 .Net Framework,